# How to create those interconnected wiki page links?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, wiki, mediawiki

I am trying to create a simple wiki with ruby on rails and i am wondering how to create interwiki links, like the one in mediawiki - for example [[PageName]]..

any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

many ruby wiki solutions around, eg take a look at the rwiki gem for a total solution or a parser like wikicloth 
https://github.com/nricciar/wikicloth
Cheers

Comment: i see. but is there a place, where i can learn or know how to write one from scratch. so i can make some custom changes... ?

Comment: @JeetSharma By looking at the source for any of the existing Ruby solutions? It's quite simple in concept: if you see `[[foo]]`, there's (hopefully) a page named `"foo"`. That page has a link (what it is depends on the wiki). Replace `[[foo]]` with a link and appropriate link text.

Comment: it is not that difficult, i once wrote the support wiki at work in ASP (vbscript) at that time and Ruby is ideal for that kind of work